# Animate LENGTH of border-bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a navbar. On hover of any of it menu item I want to have the exact same effect of border-bottom animation as in [here](http://matthewhartman.github.io/base/) (See how the border or menu items at the top-left animates when you hover them.)

I tried to find similar asked questions on stackoverflow and also on google but I didn't find anything helpful.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It's not javaascript. It's a pseudo element whose width is transitioned via `transform:scale` on hover of the parent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it was as easy as inspecting the web with the developer tools. What they do in that page is to create an element inside the menu using the `:before` pseudo-element. On hover they use CSS transforms (scale) to change the length.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6w27/3/).

```
span
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 0px 4px;
    margin: 0px 8px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

span:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    bottom: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

span:hover:before
{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code Oscar. Works like a charm. Just a quick correction on line 21 of your Fiddle: "transition: transform: 0.2s ease-in;" has an extra colon after "transform". Thought you might want to know.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have the border a different length to the element that it surrounds. However you can achieve a similar effect using just CSS - with a pseudo element. How about something like the following:

```
div:after{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    height:1px;
    width:0%;
    background-color:#444;
    display:block;
    content:'';
    transition:0.3s;
}

div:hover:after{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bese6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Its not border-bottom, it is done using css pusedo element `:before`

```
.navigation li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

.navigation li a::before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```